# flask caching - handle exception when redis service is down

Tags: python, flask, redis, flask-caching

I have a simple code using flask:

```
@app.route('/foo/<arg>')
@app.cache.memoize()
def foo_response(arg):
    return 'Hello ' + arg
```

This is working great while my redis server (cache server) is up.

If the redis server goes down, an exception is raised every time I query `/foo/<arg>`, which is understandable.

How (and where) can I handle that exception (à la try-except) in order to not use the redis server if it is down at that moment?

Comment: You can put `@app.cache.memoize` inside another decorator that has try except in itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually implemented this way. By checking the source of `memoize()` in Flask-Cache package you see

```
        try:
            cache_key = decorated_function.make_cache_key(f, *args, **kwargs)
            rv = self.cache.get(cache_key)
        except Exception:
            if current_app.debug:
                raise
            logger.exception("Exception possibly due to cache backend.")
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
```

This means if you are on production i.e. `app.debug=False` you will see the exception log and the function will be called normally.

Comment: That's great! I was thinking that but your answer makes it really clear. There could be a way to catch that exception log?

Comment: I believe you can do that by defining a custom handler and attaching it to `flask_cache` logger. There you could do what you want with the logs.